# Comparing a list in a text file to a second large text file and printing the matches.

Tags: python

I have the running configuration of a firewall saved as a text file that is roughly 67,000 lines in length. When a request comes to me to add new connectivity via this firewall I need to check if the requested host names are already being used in this running configuration. The request may sometimes be a list of over 200 host names that need to be checked.

I am trying to write a script that allows me to check this list of host names for any matches in the running configuration and provides an output (to another text file) of all matches that it finds.

The issue I am having is that the format of the host's in a request looks something like "ipdvi.tcif.hhadr.com", however in the configuration they exist with a prefix "object network obj-net-" so the line in the configuration would read "object network obj-net-ipdvi.tcif.hhadr.com". Therefore I require the script to match only part of a text string and not the whole line.

I have no experience with python but am trying to find a way to avoid going through and searching each host one-by-one in the text editor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to get this done the *fastest* possible way, but it could be done like this:

First, read your hostnames and store them in a list. I'm assuming your hostnames are saved in a separate file, one hostname per line.

Second, read your firewall configuration line by line and check if there's one of the entries in the hostname list in this line. Store the configuration line if there is a match.

```
# get hostnames as list
with open('/path/to/hostname_file.txt', 'r') as hosts:
    hostnames = [line.strip() for line in hosts.readlines()]

# read config
with open('/path/to/fw/config.txt', 'r') as fw_config:
    # file where matches are written
    with open('/path/to/matches.txt', 'w+') as match:
        # check config
        for line in fw_config:
            if any(name in line for name in hostnames):
                # write match to file
                match.write(line)
```

The result file is created/overwritten on every script execution, so you might want to backup existing result files - or change the filename in the script.

#### Update:

According to the comment, it's wanted to get only one (possibly the first) match of a hostname. This is how i'd do that:

```
with open('/path/to/hostname_file.txt', 'r') as hosts:
    hostnames = [line.strip() for line in hosts.readlines()]

with open('/path/to/fw/config.txt', 'r') as fw_config:
    with open('/path/to/matches.txt', 'w+') as match:
        for line in fw_config:
            if len(hostnames) < 1:
                break
            if any(name in line for name in hostnames):
                match.write(line)
                hostnames.remove(name)
```

Almost the same as before, but a matching hostname is now removed from the list. That way it's just not present anymore for the next check with the next line.

That also means the list of hostnames is shrinking. Any match will be removed and after matching every name, `hostnames` is just an empty list. This is why before looking for the hostnames, it's checked if there still are any names left. If not, the loop and code just exists - after having a result for each hostname, there is nothing else to do.

Of course, this should also be way faster than the previous script.

Comment: Hi XPH. Thanks a lot for your help. This works well and is showing up any pre-configured hosts for me. The only thing I would ask is if there was any way that you know of whereby the output file only shows a single match for each host in the list? Maybe just the first one? This definitely does what I was trying to achieve but a single match for each hosts would clean the output up a bit. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Nick-14: I'm glad it worked:-) I'm updating my answer, writing an example that matches only the first occurrence of a hostname in the configuration file.